# Access Query returning One (1) wrong result

Tags: microsoft-access

I have a DB that has employee information. When I run a query I include Resignation Date as one of the columns and I place "Is Null" in the criteria to leave out all resigned employees.

When I run any query, there is one specific employee who keeps coming out in results anyway. I have reentered their resignation date to make sure it's in there. I have also tried to exclude this one person by last name, and by ID. No matter what I do to try to exclude her, she keeps popping up in the queries.

What is wrong with my DB that this keeps happening?

Comment: Have you tried deleting & re-entering that particular record? Have you tried compacting/repairing the database?

Comment: I have compacted and repaired. I can't delete and reenter because that will change the primary key of the info and that is not an option.